# Unable to Post Data in my JSON File

Tags: javascript, json, post

**Unable to Perform Post method on my JSON File**
    My JSON File is 
    [{
    "name": "Help",
    "description": "Deletion not allowed for products!?",
    "price": 100000.0 }]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Product Management</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Function for Getting the Values**

```
<script>              
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'test.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    $("#abc").append($('<li>', {
                        text: element.name
                    }))
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Function for Posting the Values in the JSON file**

```
<script>   
function sumbitForm(){
var x=document.getElementById("#name");
var y=document.getElementById("#description");
var z=document.getElementById("#price");    
var Product={"name":x, "description":y, "price":z };
$.ajax({
url: "test.json",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json",
data: JSON.stringify(Product)
});
}
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ol id="abc">
</ol>
</div>
<div class="container">
```

**Input Form for posting the Data**

```
<form  name="PForm" action="" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Product Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Description:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Descrpition" rows="8"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Price:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Price">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary Right" onClick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? What exactly isn't working? What error do you get?

Comment: There is no Error but no data is being pushed in the JSON file

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the **value** of the elements, like

```
var x=document.getElementById("#name").value;
```

Else you would send the DOM elements (which, converted to a string, would only be 'object')